# OS specific value assignment to strings in c++

Tags: c++, string

I tried to assign value to a string depending on the OS,
 the code is below

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string path;
#ifdef __linux__
    path = "/temp";

#elif _WIN32
    path = "c://temp";
#endif
```

This gives an error: "âpathâ does not name a type"

But this code works correctly

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#ifdef __linux__
    string path = "temp";
#elif _WIN32
    string path = "c://temp";
#endif
```

Can anyone Explain this behavior?

Comment: The typos in this code don't make any difference. Calm down yer close finger.

Comment: The question is obvious regardless of the typo. Close-because-of-typo is meant to weed out questions like "why am i getting an error" due to  a missing semicolon or so, it's not meant to prevent bad grammar in an otherwise perfectly understandable question. They are very different reasons. Closing this question because of a missing `#endif` is being way too pedantic, missing the entire point of the question.

Comment: You can initialize variables at file scope by including the initialization with the declaration/definition.  You cannot make assignments at files scope; assignments must be inside a function.  That's why the first code snippet fails and the second works.